# Existence of local repository for private projects?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, repository

I have no experience with version control system, but I heard many advantages of using this type of system.
So, what's best program/thing I can use to store my projects in local files (not in external servers like github)?
I want something like git in my local computer only for me. Does anything like this exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default git works just fine as a local repository. So yes, it exists.

Comment: Any changes in files is saving on git servers or only local? Is my project visible on web?

Comment: @exexe Git works entirely on your local file system. The only part that needs a remote is if other people want to see your work, which you obviously don't want. You cannot "by accident" publish your work. You would have to add the URL of a server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Subversion locally without any server. [SVNBook | Version Control the Subversion Way](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/basic/in-action/#svn.advanced.reposurls).